# Get PHP array in desired format

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting the `array` from a `api request` for images which is the format as shown below. This `array` is very difficult to traverse and difficult for me to upload. I want a `array` in the single index which contains all the information of a single image. I have below given error:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => prog-programming_00267956.png
            [1] => programming-wallpaper_17695.jpg
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/png
            [1] => image/jpeg
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /tmp/php0azGbU
            [1] => /tmp/phpyByFGB
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 587659
            [1] => 83817
        )

)
```

I have to convert it to:

```
    Array
    (
       [0] => Array
      (
        [name] => prog-programming_00267956.png
        [type] => image/png
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phphSShmd
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 587659
      )
   [1] => Array
      (
        [name] => prog-programming_00267956.png
        [type] => image/png
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phphSShmd
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 587659
      )
    )
```

So how to convert array into the above format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty smple.

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $key1 => $value1) {
  foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
    $result[$key2][$key1] = $value2;
  }
}
```